# Object and other files aren't getting deployed with MavensMate

Tags: mavensmate, deployment

When I select 'Deploy to Server' from the MavensMate menu (Using Sublime 3), the only files that get deployed are .page, .trigger and .cls files. I would expect all files, including objects, layouts, etc. to be deployed. I've included the mm_apex_file_extensions portion of my user settings and you can see that it includes all file extensions. Can anyone tell me how I can get all the files to deploy?

Thanks!

```
"mm_apex_file_extensions": [
        ".page",
        ".component",
        ".cls",
        ".object",
        ".trigger",
        ".layout",
        ".resource",
        ".remoteSite",
        ".labels", 
        ".app",
        ".dashboard",
        ".permissionset",
        ".workflow",
        ".email",
        ".profile",
        ".scf",
        ".queue",
        ".reportType",
        ".report",
        ".weblink",
        ".tab",
        ".letter",
        ".role",
        ".homePageComponent",
        ".homePageLayout",
        ".objectTranslation",
        ".flow",
        ".datacategorygroup",
        ".snapshot",
        ".site",
        ".sharingRules",
        ".settings",
        ".callCenter",
        ".community",
        ".authProvider",
        ".customApplicationComponent",
        ".quickAction",
        ".approvalProcess",
        ".html",
        ".apxc",
        ".apxt"
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mm_apex_file_extensions` property only affects which files MavensMate considers an Apex file.  You need to make sure that either your `project.xml` file contains the relevant data, or that you manually select the proper metadata types and files to deploy when you use the Deploy to Server command.

Comment: Charles is correct. You can also adjust these settings on the edit project window in the project metadata tab.